# CSS grid auto in grid-template-areas

Tags: css, css-grid

I have the following CSS:

```
.card {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 40px;
    grid-template-rows: fit-content(10px) fit-content(10px) auto;
    grid-template-areas:
      "image image"
      "description slider"
      "details slider";
  }

.image-block {
    grid-area: image;
}

.description-block {
    grid-area: description;
}

.details-block {
    grid-area: details;
}

.slider-block {
   grid-area: slider;
   min-height: 300px;
}
```

what I am trying to achieve is that my description block only takes up as much space as the content inside of there, and then the details block takes up the rest. This is because the content of the description block is usually smaller than 150 pixels, so I would like the details block to start right under the description block, so it looks nicer.

but what happens is that both these blocks always get the equal amount of space. so if the content of the description block happens to take up only 50 pixels, then it still has 100 pixels of empty space before the details block starts.

is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: maybe `grid-template-rows: auto auto 1fr;` ?

Comment: can you add some HTML as well to understand better?

Comment: @TemaniAfif thanks! that did the trick :)